# Reversing scaled values in LibSVM

Tags: scale, libsvm

I am using Support Vector Regression for forecasting in LibSVM. I work it all. However there's one question that sticks in my head.

For LibSVM, I firstly scale my training and testing set in the same range and then select the optimal parameters. After I run svm-train and svm-predict, I get the forecasted values for testing set in a scaled format. I am using Excel and reverse the scaling and calculate Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE).

I a pretty sure that scaling in LibSVM works like that subtracting the value from the minimum and then dividing by the range for particular feature. However, I wanted to see whether the values I scaled by hand and the values scaled by LibSVM are the same. Before I divide the dataset into two sets, I find minimum and maximum of values in the feature and then do the scaling in the way I said above. However the scaling values for training and testing sets that LibSVM gives are not exactly the same with the ones I calculate by hand. They are just roughly close. Does anyone know why they are not the same?

Another question is that: How can I calculate MAPE in LibSVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect the file **svm-scale.c** you will find that the formula that scales data is:

```
value = y_lower + (y_upper-y_lower) * (value - y_min)/(y_max-y_min);
```

Where `y_lower` `y_upper` are `y` scaling limits

So as you can see the scaled value is not worked out as you were supposing *"subtracting the value from the minimum and then dividing by the range for particular feature"*. If you want to recover the real value you only have to undo the formula.

**Example:**

If you take one the many datasets that are available in the libSVM site as examples, such as this one: [`covtype dataset`](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/binary.html#covtype.binary), and you open it, you will see a file such this one:

```
1 1:2596 2:51 3:3 4:258 6:510 7:221 8:232 9:148 10:6279 11:1 43:1
1 1:2590 2:56 3:2 4:212 5:-6 6:390 7:220 8:235 9:151 10:6225 11:1 43:1
2 1:2804 2:139 3:9 4:268 5:65 6:3180 7:234 8:238 9:135 10:6121 11:1 26:1
2 1:2785 2:155 3:18 4:242 5:118 6:3090 7:238 8:238 9:122 10:6211 11:1 44:1
1 1:2595 2:45 3:2 4:153 5:-1 6:391 7:220 8:234 9:150 10:6172 11:1 43:1
...
```

Now let's scale it using:

```
./svm-scale -s covtype.libsvm.binary.range  covtype.libsvm.binary > covtype.libsvm.binary.scale
```

This will generate two files, the `.range` file will contain all the information related to the scale process (max and min per column), and the `.scale` file which is the output, that will look like:

```
1 1:-0.262631 2:-0.716667 3:-0.909091 4:-0.630637 5:-0.552972 6:-0.856681 7:0.740157 8:0.826772 9:0.165354 10:0.750732 11:1 12:-1 13:-1 14:-1 15:-1 16:-1 17:-1 18:-1 19:-1 20:-1 21:-1 22:-1 23:-1 24:-1 25:-1 26:-1 27:-1 28:-1 29:-1 30:-1 31:-1 32:-1 33:-1 34:-1 35:-1 36:-1 37:-1 38:-1 39:-1 40:-1 41:-1 42:-1 43:1 44:-1 45:-1 46:-1 47:-1 48:-1 49:-1 50:-1 51:-1 52:-1 53:-1 54:-1 
1 1:-0.268634 2:-0.688889 3:-0.939394 4:-0.696492 5:-0.568475 6:-0.890403 7:0.732283 8:0.850394 9:0.188976 10:0.735675 11:1 12:-1 13:-1 14:-1 15:-1 16:-1 17:-1 18:-1 19:-1 20:-1 21:-1 22:-1 23:-1 24:-1 25:-1 26:-1 27:-1 28:-1 29:-1 30:-1 31:-1 32:-1 33:-1 34:-1 35:-1 36:-1 37:-1 38:-1 39:-1 40:-1 41:-1 42:-1 43:1 44:-1 45:-1 46:-1 47:-1 48:-1 49:-1 50:-1 51:-1 52:-1 53:-1 54:-1 
2 1:-0.0545273 2:-0.227778 3:-0.727273 4:-0.616321 5:-0.385013 6:-0.106365 7:0.84252 8:0.874016 9:0.0629921 10:0.706678 11:1 12:-1 13:-1 14:-1 15:-1 16:-1 17:-1 18:-1 19:-1 20:-1 21:-1 22:-1 23:-1 24:-1 25:-1 26:1 27:-1 28:-1 29:-1 30:-1 31:-1 32:-1 33:-1 34:-1 35:-1 36:-1 37:-1 38:-1 39:-1 40:-1 41:-1 42:-1 43:-1 44:-1 45:-1 46:-1 47:-1 48:-1 49:-1 50:-1 51:-1 52:-1 53:-1 54:-1 
2 1:-0.0735368 2:-0.138889 3:-0.454545 4:-0.653543 5:-0.248062 6:-0.131657 7:0.874016 8:0.874016 9:-0.0393701 10:0.731772 11:1 12:-1 13:-1 14:-1 15:-1 16:-1 17:-1 18:-1 19:-1 20:-1 21:-1 22:-1 23:-1 24:-1 25:-1 26:-1 27:-1 28:-1 29:-1 30:-1 31:-1 32:-1 33:-1 34:-1 35:-1 36:-1 37:-1 38:-1 39:-1 40:-1 41:-1 42:-1 43:-1 44:1 45:-1 46:-1 47:-1 48:-1 49:-1 50:-1 51:-1 52:-1 53:-1 54:-1 
1 1:-0.263632 2:-0.75 3:-0.939394 4:-0.780959 5:-0.555556 6:-0.890122 7:0.732283 8:0.84252 9:0.181102 10:0.720898 11:1 12:-1 13:-1 14:-1 15:-1 16:-1 17:-1 18:-1 19:-1 20:-1 21:-1 22:-1 23:-1 24:-1 25:-1 26:-1 27:-1 28:-1 29:-1 30:-1 31:-1 32:-1 33:-1 34:-1 35:-1 36:-1 37:-1 38:-1 39:-1 40:-1 41:-1 42:-1 43:1 44:-1 45:-1 46:-1 47:-1 48:-1 49:-1 50:-1 51:-1 52:-1 53:-1 54:-1 
...
```

The `.range` file looks like:

```
x
-1 1
1 1859 3858
2 0 360
3 0 66
4 0 1397
...
```

So taking into account that `y_lower = -1` and `y_upper = 1` you can verify for the first element `2596` the conversion:

```
value = -1 + (1 - (-1)) * (2596 - 1859) / (3858 - 1859) = -0.26263131565782893
```

Which is the expected value :)

**Tip:**

Normally you scale your training set with `svm-scale`, get your model (using k-fold cross validation) and finally performing testing scaling data with the values (`y_max` and `y_min`) obtained from training. You can see the process in the file `tools/easy.py`.

Comment: oh thank you so much. I am using cmd mode for LibSVM. My data set is in another folder. Thus, `.range` file is created in LibSVM/Windows folder, `.scale` file is created in the folder where your data set is. My lower and upper values are 0 and 1, respectively. Hence, this gives the formula I mentioned previously, which is "subtracting the value from the minimum and then dividing by the range for particular feature". Anyway, much obliged for your help! That's an easy question but a great answer!