# How to convert scaled data into original data in SVM

Tags: svm, scaling, libsvm

I am new to SVM. I am using Support Vector Regression for forecasting in LibSVM. For LibSVM, I firstly scaled [0,1] my training and testing set in the same range and then select the optimal parameters. After I run svm-train and svm-predict, I got the predicted values for testing set in a scaled format.How do i get the original values back for output? Which conversion I need to use.

svm-scale -l 0 -u 1 -s range uni.train> unitrain.scale

svm-scale -r range uni.test > unitest.scale

svm-train -c 32768 -g 0.03125 unitrain.scale

svm-predict unitest.scale unitrain.scale.model uni.txt

Accuracy = 87.5% (266/304) (classification)

svm-train -s 3 -c 32768 -g 0.03125 unitrain.scale

svm-predict unitest.scale unitrain.scale.model uni.txt

Mean squared error = 0.558619 (regression)

Squared correlation coefficient = 0.514304 (regression)

After this, the output is uni.txt i.e. 0.619153  -1.10326 -0.94956 ........ -1.00426 -0.311161 -0.725936

How do i get the original values for output in uni.txt, these are in scaled format?

Comment: please be specific about "original values back for output" bit more

Comment: Hi DavisJhons, I have edited the question with specific detials, kindly look at this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to convert scale values  into your original values ?

Comment: Yes, if you can provide a formula or equation that will help me.

Comment: But there is no inbuilt function for this , you have to find how scaling is being done and reverse it. Can you post a sample of scaled values and original values with the range ?

Comment: File : range

x

0 1

1 15 97

2 15.35 101

3 14.65 94.15000000000001

4 488806 172720362

5 -7.19721131923505 2.96756858764957

6 19.5830445864842 80.4774100045387

7 0 1

8 -1.37254901960784 0.986577181208054

9 -1.32026143790849 0.970979020979021

10 -1.25170068027211 0.951013807148654

Comment: File: unitest.scale after scaling to [0,1]

1 1:0.00426829 2:0.00525394 3:0.00754717 4:0.230975 5:0.682322 6:0.476001 7:1 8:0.887002 9:0.798431 10:0.782243 

-1 1:0.0103659 2:0.0081728 3:0.00628931 4:0.285028 5:0.682061 6:0.391304 7:0.579319 8:0.734403 9:0.791534 10:0.785905 

1 1:0.00243902 3:0.00566038 4:0.122708 5:0.682154 6:0.391304 7:0.579319 8:0.734403 9:0.785715 10:0.792593

Comment: File: uni.test before scaling to [0,1]

+1 1:15.35 2:15.8 3:15.25 4:40269936 5:-0.261561820579287 6:48.5688464350416 7:1 8:0.719999999999999 9:0.509135802469135 10:0.471358024691358

-1 1:15.85 2:16.05 3:15.15 4:49579646 5:-0.264208002646376 6:43.4112240192739 7:0.579319019045384 8:0.359999999999999 9:0.493333333333333 10:0.479423868312757

+1 1:15.2 2:15.35 3:15.1 4:21623023 5:-0.263270304805534 6:43.4112240192739 7:0.579319019045384 8:0.359999999999999 9:0.479999999999999 10:0.494156378600822

Comment: Hi DavisJhons, i have given after scaling and before scaling for 3 data set points for test data set. Let me know how can i reverse it back to original data.

Comment: i found this, please try with your data http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26499/how-to-undo-feature-scaling-normalization-for-output

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the previous post, i also checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244109/reversing-scaled-values-in-libsvm,  it is same as that.  What i wanted to know is that the predicted output values back to original? Since i am new to LIBSVM, please make me understand about the ouput values. For example i have used 1 to 10 features, and a class label in test file. Does the output value in uni.txt 0.619153 is needs to be mulitplied with some featues to get the exact value? Am i right ?